# GitKraken ignoring server-side pre-receive hooks?

Tags: windows, git, githooks, gitkraken

Does GitKraken bypass server-side pre-receive hooks?

I have a commit I want to push to the server.

However (for testing purposes), I've set a trivial `pre-receive` hook on the server which rejects any and all pushes and creates a file (as a signal the hook's running):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo tests > $PWD/../x.txt
exit 1
```

If I use Git Bash (for Windows), my push obviously gets rejected, but file `x.txt` is created out of the server repo:

```
$ git push
[...]
To server/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'server/repo.git'
```

However, if I perform the push via GitKraken, the push goes through, and `x.txt` is not created! Running `git log` on the server confirms that the push went through, so GitKraken isn't lying.

How's this possible? These hooks aren't shown on the [relevant GitKraken support page](https://support.gitkraken.com/working-with-repositories/githooks/), but I assume that's because those are all local hooks (`pre-commit/rebase`, etc). I can't understand how it gets the server to ignore its own hooks...

As a reproducible example, in Git Bash:

```
cd /testdir
mkdir repo.git
cd repo.git

git init --bare
# Initialized empty Git repository in /testdir/repo.git/

cat > hooks/pre-receive << EOF
  #!/bin/bash
  echo Nope!
  echo x > ../x.txt
  exit 1
EOF

cd ..
git clone repo.git
# Cloning into 'repo'...
# warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
# done.

cd repo
touch .gitignore
git add .
git commit -m "test"
# [master (root-commit) e9b25d3] test
# Committer: Wasabi <wasabi@email.local>
# Your name and email address were configured [...]
# 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
# create mode 100644 .gitignore

git push
# Enumerating objects: 3, done.
# Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
# Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 214 bytes | 53.00 KiB/s, done.
# Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
# remote: Nope!                          # shows the hook is working
# To testdir/repo.git
#  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
# error: failed to push some refs to 'testdir/repo.git'

ls ..
# repo/  repo.git/  x.txt

rm ../x.txt

# Confirming the push really didn't go through
cd ../repo.git
git log
# fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

The `remote: Nope!` and presence of `x.txt` mean the hook was called and the `git log` shows we successfully rejected the push.

However, if I now open `repo` in GitKraken, I can simply click "Push", tell it to use the default origin/master branch, and get the notification "Push Successful: master to origin".

Confirming the push truly went through with Git Bash:

```
cd ../repo.git
git log
# Author: Wasabi <wasabi@email.local>
# Date:   Mon Oct 14 15:00:49 2019 -0300
# 
#     test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on [GitKraken's Slack channel and got my answer](https://gitkraken.slack.com/archives/C2DRKFLVB/p1571253565027100):

GitKraken doesn't actually use Git under the hood, but simply follows its protocols.

Long story short, server-side hooks would work with GitKraken if the server were remote (in which case the server's Git would naturally call the hooks). However, since my example (and real-world case) uses a local server, GitKraken manages the whole interaction. Unfortunately, GitKraken's "Git implementation" doesn't have server-side hooks.

So, GitKraken on a local server means no server-side hooks.